# What kind of "condemnation" is a believer exempt from in Romans 8:1?

Tags: protestantism, romans, judgment

I've been looking up several of my reference books for a good definition of condemnation, but evidently it's simply "judgment" based on its context, including in [Rom. 8:1](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/rom/8/1/s_1054001).

It's clear from other passages that Christians can be chastised/disciplined for their wrong ([Heb. 12:3-11](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/heb/12/3/s_1145003)) or die at the hand of God for sinning ([1 Cor. 11:27-30](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/1co/11/27/s_1073027) and [Acts 5:1-11](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/act/5/1/s_1023001)). So these examples are not the condemnation meant, since the person in Christ can't be condemned, according to the promise of Rom 8:1.

Could this condemnation therefore refer to a judgment of eternal rejection, whether preliminary in this life, or at the final Judgment Day to come, that those in Christ are exempted from?

I prefer answers from Protestants who accept the Apostle's Creed.

Comment: "Condemnation" is not just "judgement", it is specifically "negative judgement". If you are judged "guilty" then you are condemned. If you are judged "innocent" then you are not condemned.

Comment: This might fit better on [Stack Exchange Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions) where the word κατάκριμα [Strong 2631](https://biblehub.com/greek/2631.htm) can be examined in detail.

Comment: @NigelJ You mean I can post it in both places?

Comment: @Steve Cross-posting is generally frowned upon within Stack Exchange. My thought was that the Moderators of SE-C may migrate the question to SE-BH if they think that is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate context in Romans 8 gives the answer definitively. "For the law of the Spirit of life in Christ Jesus hath made me free from the law of sin and death.". The law of sin and death is what the believer is freed from, therefore death is the condemnation being spoken of. Instead of getting what we deserve ( death due to sin) we receive life through the Spirit because Christ died for us.

Although Christians still die, this will be reversed at Christ's coming for the church. Death will not be permanent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed John 3:18 indicates that those who do not believe in God's only Son are already condemned (dead) already and John 5:24 that believers have crossed from death (condemnation) to life (no condemnation).